# Binding one collection to multiple tabs with filters

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, data-binding, .net-3.5

In my small WPF project, I have a `TabControl` with three tabs.  On each tab is a `ListBox`.  This project keeps track of groceries we need to buy.  (No, it's not homework, it's for my wife.)  So I have a list of `ShoppingListItem`s, each of which has a `Name` and a `Needed` property: `true` when we need the item, and `false` after we buy it.

So the three tabs are All, Bought, and Needed.  They should all point to the same `ShoppingListItemCollection` (which inherits from `ObservableCollection<ShoppingListItem>`).  But Bought should only show the items where Needed is false, and Needed should only show items where Needed is true.  (The All tab has checkboxes on the items.)

This doesn't seem *that* hard, but after a couple hours, I'm no closer to figuring this out.  It seems like a CollectionView or CollectionViewSource is what I need, but I can't get anything to happen; I check and uncheck the boxes on the All tab, and the items on the other two tabs just sit there staring at me.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've found that in WPF, there are 5000 ways to do data binding.  Unfortunately, only about 3 of them are correct.  The other 4997 give incomprehensible errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx) to reuse the original collection with a filter.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="NeededItems" Source="{Binding Items}" Filter="NeededCollectionViewSource_Filter" />
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="BoughtItems" Source="{Binding Items}" Filter="BoughtCollectionViewSource_Filter" />
</Window.Resources>

<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="All">
        <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Bought">
        <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource BoughtItems}}" />
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Needed">
        <ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource NeededItems}}" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Some code behind is required for the filter.

```
private void NeededCollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Accepted = ((ShoppingListItem) e.Item).Needed;
}

private void BoughtCollectionViewSource_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    e.Accepted = !((ShoppingListItem) e.Item).Needed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ideas:

1. When tabs Bought and Needed load, filter them yourself by creating new collections with the items you want, or
2. when tabs Bought and Needed load, override the list item databind and toggle visability based on Needed